# Jquery "Autocomplete" with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I'm following this link to build a multiple values auto complete system using jquery, php and mysql. e.g : If I type something in input fields it will show me a search result in input box and again if a search another terms it will show me another result which will show the result with comma separate. Like this link does :  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote. Code is following :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple, remote</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
  background: white url("loading-image.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
  }
  function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
  }

  $( "#birds" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
          $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "search.php", {
          term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
      },
      search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
          return false;
        }
      },
      focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
      }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>   

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds" size="50">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Php cdoe (It's not fully complete because I don't understand what I need to do in this php page.)

```
<?php
require_once("../frontend/config.php");
$term = $_GET['term'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT family_name FROM contact_details WHERE family_name LIKE '%$term%' ");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $family_name = $res['family_name'];
    echo json_encode($family_name);
}
?>
```

Can something help me about it how can I show the search result like the link does ? Note : I'm learning Jquery :) Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I did this. Php code should like this :

```
<?php
require_once("../frontend/config.php");
$term = $_GET['term'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT family_name FROM contact_details WHERE family_name LIKE '%$term%' ");
 $return_arr = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['label'] = $row['family_name'];
    //$row_array['value'] = $row['tags_list'];
    //$row_array['abbrev'] = $row['abbrev'];

    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```